# PHP, how extend waiting time from apache server for display progress bar

Tags: javascript, php, apache

The problem,  I use SOAP to return informations, almost 75150 or more records and I need insert into sql server, this take a long time.

I was working with several progress bar, all this works correctly in certain time, and later stop, I realize the problem is the waiting server time, the progress bar works correctly, when server keeps "waiting for localhost", but when this disappears and the forward and backward arrows are enabled, the progress bar dosen't work, but in the back, the insertions continue.

Exist some method to work this approach.

CODE

```
  ini_set ( "memory_limit", "512M" ); // Aumento de memoria
  ini_set ( 'max_execution_time', 15400 ); // minutos
  ini_set ( 'soap.wsdl_cache_enabled', 1 ); // original 0
  ini_set ( 'soap.wsdl_cache_ttl', '86400' ); // original 0, suggest 3600
  ini_set('output_buffering', 0);

 public function processOrdersDetails(SoapClient $clienteSOAP) {

        echo "Consultando...\n";

        $response = $clienteSOAP->viewAllOrdersDataDetails ( array (
                'val' => 'somevaluehere',
                'val2' => 'anothervaluehere' 
        ) );

        $size = count ( ( array ) $response->Result->DetailsData );

        for($i = 0; $i < $size; $i ++) {

            $orderd = new \entidad\orderDetails ();
            $percent =  ($i / $size * 100)  . "%";

            // Javascript for updating the progress bar and information
            echo '<script language="javascript">
                    document.getElementById("progress").innerHTML="<div style=\"width:' . $percent . ';background-color:#ddd;\">&nbsp;</div>";
                    document.getElementById("information").innerHTML="' . $i . ' row(s) processed.";
                    </script>';

            // This is for the buffer achieve the minimum size in order to flush data
            echo str_repeat ( ' ', 1024 * 64 );

            // Send output to browser immediately
            flush ();

            // Sleep one second so we can see the delay
            sleep ( 1 );

            $orderd->orderID = $response->Result->DetailsData [$i]->orderID;

            // Insert
            $logorderd->insert ( $orderd );
            // fin
        }

        echo '<script language="javascript">document.getElementById("information").innerHTML="Process completed"</script>';
    }
```

Comment: Add some code that you have tried.

Comment: i would run this in the background, so the user does not have to sit there staring at a progress bar

Comment: You might me hitting a memory limit when doing all those processing. Do you have error reporting enabled to be able to see if an error occurs  when the processing stop? As Dagon said, you should add this to a background process, maybe using something like RabbitMQ or GearMan, and add the records in batch processes at a time (maybe with an email notification of when the processing is complete)

Comment: the memory works correctly with memory_limit, the process in self doesn't stop, only the progress bar, the inserts continues in background, exist some method to keep progress update?, lets say every 30 seconds check the status and display, even if the process is in the background?